# Complement of a set. Homework Help.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I stumbled upon this question in my assignment.

**1. Write complement of $A= \{x: x$ is a prime number $\}$.**

It looked pretty easy and I answered it as...

*Answer 1.* **$A= \{x : x$ is a composite number$\}$ -1**  ------>      1

I know that 1 is neither prime nor composite so I, in  order to depict it's separation from the set of composite numbers wrote it as in statement 1 beside a subtraction sign.

Meanwhile, I looked at the original solution and found it to be...

*Original Answer 1.* **$A= \{x : x$ is a positive composite number and $x = 1\}$** ---->2

Now my doubts..

*1. Which one out of these two statements 1 and 2 is actually correct?*

*2. If statement 2 is correct then why 1 has been written as **$x=1$** in between the brackets?*

*3. How would statement 2 look like in roster form?*

*4. Am I missing some concept here?*

Thank You.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts. I don’t know if it’s imperative to this post, but just in general it is a wonderful formatting tool.

Comment: I thought that this time the question could just be written without mathjax so I did not use it. I always avoid it if I can. It is just time consuming.It is necessary,I know. But not always. Right? or is it?

Comment: It’s not *always* necessary. And I dispute that it’s time consuming. I promise you that formatting your posts with MathJax and built-in tools like embedded hyperlinks and block quotes is in your best interest.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I think it is time consuming when I use it for depicting the math signs that can be depicted by keyboard keys itself. What is your take?

Comment: The last thing I’m going to say (so that the comment section of this question doesn’t overflow) is that MSE is a very prestigious Q&A site with rigorous standards. Part of that is clear notation and aesthetically agreeable posts that look polished and professional. In my opinion, one should use MathJax whenever doing so would improve a post. It gets faster as one hones his skills.

Comment: @Chase Ryan Taylor  I have understood the importance of MathJax. I would always use it no matter what. This site is giving so much to me. At least, I should too do something to add value to it's content. I would always be careful from now on. Got it.;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current wording your statement 2 is not correct since $x$ cannot be both composite and $1$. The answer here would be $\textbf{A}^c = \{x: x \text{ is a composite number or } x=1\}$. This is only if $\textbf{A}$ is in the universe of the natural numbers. First you have to specify the universe.

Also statement 1 isn't correct since it does not contain $1$, and isn't valid notation anyway.

Comment: What about statement 1?

Comment: @SakshamSharma Indeed you can't substract a number from a set, that's not definied.

Comment: Why is there a need to mention 1? As the question asks for complement of  prime number. Then isn't it enough to just write A'= {x : x is a composite number}  ?

Comment: @SakshamSharma Well $1$ isn't a prime number, is it? So it's not contained in the set of all prime numbers, and thus it is contained in the complement of that set.

Comment: It's just a matter of definition 1 is not definied as a composite number but it isn't prime either, so you have to add it in the set explicitly.

Comment: But 1 is neither composite. Then how can it be written along with composite numbers like this?

Comment: @ keep_On_Cruising if 1 is not defined as composite number and nor prime and the question asks for complement of prime number then WHY? Why is it written explicitly? Is there any need for it?

Comment: @SakshamSharma Remember the definition of the complement of a set. If we have the set of all prime numbers, the complement of it is not the set of all composites, but the set of all numbers that are not prime. And $1$ is clearly not prime.

Comment: @Huffman_Coding "Remember the definition of the complement of a set. If we have the set of all prime numbers, the complement of it is not the set of all composites, but the set of all numbers that are not prime." Is there any difference between "the set of all composites" and "the set of all numbers that are not prime?"

Comment: @SakshamSharma If you still have difficulties understaning it, you should look up the definitions of a composite number and a prime number on the web, I'm sure you will understand it then. :)

Comment: @Keep_On_Cruising No need. Prime number= a number with 2 factors. And composite number = more than 2 factors.

Comment: @SakshamSharma A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself. So one 1 is excluded from the primes by definition.

Comment: @SakshamSharma Yes! There is a difference, and you mentioned it before. $1$ is the reason they're not the same in the natural numbers. $1$ is not prime, and not composite.

Comment: The question asks for complement of prime numbers (taking N as universe). Then the answer is either 1 or "composites" because when I take out prime numbers from universe N then what I am left with is 1 and "composites". So is that the reason that the answer is A'= {x : x is a composite number or 1}?

Comment: @SakshamSharma Exactly!

Comment: @Huffman_Coding One more question. In the answer, you gave that " x : x is a positive composite number or x=1." Why "positive composite number"? Aren't composite numbers always positive? Can't we just write the "set of composite numbers"?

Comment: @SakshamSharma Yeah sorry, changed.

Comment: Thanks guys! I understood. Persistence paid off. ;) More questions coming though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68200/discussion-between-saksham-sharma-and-huffman-coding).